# How to modify launchSettings.json in order to point to index.html

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I'm largely a newbie to ASP.NET Core. I created a Web API template and setup a controller, then manually created the following directory structure under `wwwroot`:

```
wwwroot/
  css/
    site.css
  js/
    site.js
  index.html
```

When I hit F5, I want to launch `index.html` in the browser. However, I can't figure out how to do this. Here's my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63123/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

When I run the "IIS Express" command in Chrome, I get "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:63123/index.html". Why is this happening?

The full source of my app is available here: https://github.com/jamesqo/Decaf/tree/webapp-2/Decaf.WebApp.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded your code and changed your launchsettings file to the fully qualified url:

```
"launchUrl": "http://localhost:63123/index.html",
```

I also amended your StartUp.cs adding  (app.UseStaticFiles();) and it now seems to work:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Result on running:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just tried your suggestion, though, and it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked when I added `app.UseFileServer()`. Can you please update your answer to say that?

Comment: You can answer the question yourself if you found the solution. Sorry mine didn't work. The only other thing I did was change your launchurl to be fully qualified (I downloaded your code). Will add that to my answer in case it's helpful to someone else in the future. I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .UseContentRoot to the BuildWebHost method of your Program.cs file, like this:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .Build();
```

then, configure the program to use static files by adding .UseStaticFiles() to the Configure method in your Startup class. You also need to configure the MVC middleware to listen to and handle the incoming request. You can see where I have configured routes in app.UseMvc().

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Lastly, navigate to http://localhost:63123/index.html and you should be good to go.